# definitions of hyperbolic fixed points for a flow and a map

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-points

The definition of a hyperbolic fixed point for a map is

> Let $p\in M$ be a fixed point of f. Then p is a $\textbf{hyperbolic fixed point}$ if none of the eigenvales of $DF_{p}$ are on the unit circle.

The definition for a flow is

> Let $\varphi_{t}$ be a flow generated by a vector field X. Let p be a fixed point of X. Then p is a $\textbf{hyperbolic fixed point}$ if none of the real parts of the eigenvales of $DX_{p}$ has zero real part.

Questions:

1. My understanding of the differences between flow and map is that the former is defined for continuous-time dynamical systems, while the latter is defined for discrete-time systems. Is this the only distinction?
2. Are the two definitions consistent?

I have seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885014/link-between-the-two-definitions-of-a-hyperbolic-point?rq=1), but it seems to only address the linear case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not sure if I understand this question, but yes I think so. Flows are used to define continuous-time dynamical systems and maps are used to define discrete-time dynamical system.
2. Yes, these definitions are consistent. One common way to get a discrete-time dynamical system from a continuous-time one is to look at the flow for a fixed time $\tau$. Specifically, $\phi_\tau:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is a diffeomorphism and so we can define a discrete-time dynamical system by applying the map $\phi_\tau$. The definitions are consistent in the sense that if $p$ is a hyperbolic fixed point of the continuous-time system then it is a hyperbolic fixed point for the discrete-time system. This can be shown be noting that if $p$ is a fixed point, then $[D\phi_\tau] (p) = \exp(A\tau)$ where $A$ is the matrix from linearizing around $p$. Generally, results about hyperbolic fixed points in discrete time have analogous results for continuous time and vice versa.

Comment: Thank for your reply. How do you get that $\left[D \phi_\tau\right](p)=\exp (A \tau)$?

Comment: @XXX To get the equality, I showed $\frac{d}{d\tau} [D\phi_\tau] (p) = [DF](\phi_\tau(p))[D\phi_\tau](p)$ by exchanging the order of the derivatives (here I am using $F(x)$ to denote the vector field at $x$). Then for a fixed point $p$ where $A = DF(p)$  this becomes $\frac{d}{d\tau} [D\phi_\tau] (p) = A[D\phi_\tau] (p) $ with $[D\phi_0](p) =I$, which is an matrix-valued ODE solved by $\exp(A\tau)$.